# How to convert large files of dart code to python

Tags: python, dart, binary

I wanted to convert some dart code to python code, the dart code is rather large since it has 3k lines of total code(all of the files altogether). The way i propose further is to compile the dart code to binary and then convert the binary to a .py file, is there any way i can do so?

Comment: Short answer: no. Your best bet is probably make the dart code into a library that can be called from python.

Comment: How exactly can i convert the dart files into a library to call it from python?? Never really called dart from other languages so new to this

Answer (score -1):

Anyone coming back to this question,
I would suggest a popular tool called: ChatGPT.

Use this prompt

```
convert this dart code to python code.
add some context here.
```

Maybe use the api to create a script if you have a large amount of files.

Comment: I recommend to add the missing steps: review the generated code, understand the generated code based on your sound knowledge of python (rather than dart), add at least the comment "generated by assembling of text fragements which look like python code, instead of by actually programming", test the generated code, document how the generated code was tested and the test design, the test cases, the test results. Otherwise you might find that users on StackOverflow are somewhat biased against answers which basically say "let chatGPT do the job of programmers".